# Python - Py_Initialize unresolved during compilation

Tags: python, gcc, static-libraries, unresolved-external

I have statically compiled Python2.7 without any error. 
To test my build, I use the following snippet:

```
#include "Python.h"
int main()
{
   Py_Initialize();
}
```

And I am compiling it like this:

```
$ gcc -static -I/path/to/python/header -L/path/to/my/staticpythonlib \ 
 -lpython2.7 -ldl -l_all_other_needed_lib /tmp/my_previous_snippet.c -o myouput
```

However, an error occured. gcc claims the famous `undefined reference`.

> test.c:(.text+0x1): Undefined reference to 'Py_Initialize'

Curiously I used gcc with the verbosity flag (I won't paste the result here) and the compiler says, it's using my libpython, but couldn't find the reference. So I listed the symbols of my static python2.7 library :

```
$ nm /path/to/pythonlib |grep Py_Initialize
frozenmain.o           U Py_Initialize
pythonrun.o  0000009e9 T Py_Initialize
pythonrun.o  000000052 T Py_Initialize_Ex
main.o                 U Py_Initialize
```

We can see, that `Py_Initialize` is correctly referenced in pythonrun.o. However i don't know how the compiler chose the correct object file.

My questions are :

1. How can I be sure, that gcc uses the correct object file in my .a lib?
2. Is there anything wrong on my compilation options?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is an error occurring during linkage not during compilation.

Answer (score 7):

The order matters! More specifically, the order in the arguments for gcc matters. More specifically, if a `bar` object uses a function `bluh` from library `bleh`, then the order `-lbleh bar.o` is problematic because it provides no reason to gcc look for the function `bluh` in `bleh`. On the other hand, when you use `bar.o -lbleh` then gcc knows you are referring to `bluh` and when it gets to handle `-lbleh` it tries to resolve the dependence. This is quickly mentioned at http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html. As a rule, always specifies libraries after your objects.

To reproduce your problem, create a file `a1.c` as in:

```
#include "Python.h"

int main()
{
    Py_Initialize();
    return 0;
}
```

Now compile with `gcc -static -I/usr/include/python2.7 -L/usr/lib/python2.7/config/ -lpython2.7 -ldl -lm -lutil -lz -pthread -o a1 a1.c`. This gives the undefined reference to `Py_Initialize`. Of course you have to change the paths to match your installation.

Now, instead, compile with `gcc -static -I/usr/include/python2.7 -L/usr/lib/python2.7/config/ -o a1 a1.c -lpython2.7 -ldl -lm -lutil -lz -pthread` and it works (ignoring the possible many warnings, which is a different matter).

Answer (score 1):

I am using python 2.7 and set the path of python installation directory in the environment variable.
I also use boost 1.5.0

follow the steps to Compile the below code

```
#include <python2.7/Python.h>
int main()
{
Py_Initialize();

PyRun_SimpleString("print \"Hello, world!\"");

Py_Finalize();
return 0;
}
```

Run the command:-

```
g++ hello.cc -lpython2.7
./a.out
```