# Python in C++ code [waf]

Tags: python, c++, waf, ns-3

I'm trying to develop a ns-3 code in C++ that imports some Python bindings, by using Python.h library. (**"#include python2.7/Python.h"**)

However, when I start to use Python functions (such as Py_Initialize and others), I receive an error message:

> **undefined reference to 'Py_Initialize'**

and the build fails.

How can I solve this?

I'm currently using: Ubuntu 16.10, ns-3.26, Python: 2.7.12+

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - Py\_Initialize unresolved during compilation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13782618/python-py-initialize-unresolved-during-compilation)

Comment: check if python-dev is installed in your system